# Why my core data setup didn't finish to setup on time?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

The following issue only sometimes appears, and never on my device. It happens a lot of times to users of my app.

[image]

I tried to regenerate that issue on my own device, and I simply commented it out where I setup my core data stack. And the error is the following:

[image]

In my opinion it is the same, and the reason why it happens on production is that... core data stack didn't finish to setup before it is used in the app. Am I right?

Look at below code. This is how I setup my Core Data:

```
class CoreDataManager {
    static var shared = CoreDataManager()
    private var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?
    var rootContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    var defaultContext: NSManagedObjectContext?
    func setup() {
    
        guard coordinator == nil && defaultContext == nil else {
            return
        }
        if let managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel.defaultModel {
            coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: managedObjectModel)
        
            var storePath = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: SharedGroupName)
        
            storePath = storePath!.appendingPathComponent("FieldService.sqlite")
        
            let options = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
        
            do {
                try coordinator?.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: nil, at: storePath, options: options)
                rootContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
                rootContext?.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
                rootContext?.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
                rootContext?.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
                defaultContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .mainQueueConcurrencyType)
                defaultContext?.setupDefaultContext()
                defaultContext?.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
                defaultContext?.parent = rootContext
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("SUPER ERROR>>>>>>>>>")
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is simply called here:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    CoreDataManager.shared.setup()
    // another stuff
}
```

Issue for answer from Vadian:

[image]

Comment: just **do not** use forced unwrapping in your code at all. It is a well known recipe for a crash. Use for example `if let x = ... {...}`.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but this IS NOT the case of my question. It SHOULD NOT BE NIL Why it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `CoreDataManager` is a singleton it makes no sense to implement an extra `setup` method – which will be called only once anyway – and perform `nil` checks. A better way is to implement `init` and do all the setup stuff there.

All properties in a Core Data stack – especially in a singleton – are supposed to be non-optional. Properties which depend on each other can be initialised lazily.

And `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is outdated. Apple introduced `NSPersistentContainer` many years ago.

A contemporary implementation of a Core Data stack is something like this, I commented out some lines which threw compile errors

```
class CoreDataManager {
    static let shared = CoreDataManager()
    
    private let container: NSPersistentContainer
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FieldService")
        let storedescriptionOptions = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        storedescriptionOptions.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption)
        storedescriptionOptions.setOption(true as NSNumber, forKey: NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption)
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [
            NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: SharedGroupName)!.appendingPathComponent("FieldService.sqlite")),
            storedescriptionOptions
        ]
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error { fatalError(error.localizedDescription) }
        }
    }
  
    lazy var rootContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .privateQueueConcurrencyType)
        context.persistentStoreCoordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
        // context.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
        context.mergePolicy = NSMergePolicy.mergeByPropertyObjectTrump
        return context
    }()
    
    lazy var defaultContext : NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = self.container.viewContext
        // context.setupDefaultContext()
        // context.obtainPermanentIdsBeforeSaving()
        context.parent = rootContext
        return context
    }()
}
```

Comment: Wow, you think it is better replacement of the code I have?;) If yes, you are genius;) Thank you. It looks smart and very very good. I will check it later and now I vote it up anyway;)

Comment: Hello, I have implemented your idea, but have an issue while fetching object from core data: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Context already has a coordinator;  cannot replace.'` i have edited a question to show the error.

Comment: Should not it be replaced each other? defaultContext should be rootContext?

Comment: I just tried to refactor your code to more contemporary APIs. Yes usually the provided context on the main thread is also the main context. It’s up to you to clean it up.

Comment: Ok, I managed to make it working;) it is fine...